# SQLite DB file is recreated everytime I run Java program

Tags: java, sqlite

I've created a JavaFX application that uses SQLite as the default DB. The problem is every time I run the jar file, the application recreates the DB file (thus I lose all the previous data). I have the following observations:

- Upon running my code through the IDE, this problem doesn't occur. It works perfectly.
- Only when I clean build my project and test my application directly from the Jar file, I face this problem.

I have two classes to handle the DB operations. **DatabaseConnector.java** establishes a connection with the database. **DatabaseHandler.java** has all the query related methods and uses an instance of DatabaseConnector class.

**DatabaseConnector.java**

```
    public class DatabaseConnector {
    
    public static Connection Connect(){
        try {
            String urlSqlite = "jdbc:sqlite:QRGenMaster.db";
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(urlSqlite);
            return conn;
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**DatabaseHandler.java**

```
public class DatabaseHandler {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    PreparedStatement ps =null;
    ResultSet res = null;
    ArrayList<ModelHolder> mod = new ArrayList<ModelHolder>();
      
    DatabaseHandler(){
        conn = DatabaseConnector.Connect();
        if(conn != null){
            System.out.println("Database connection established!");
            createTables();
        }else{
            System.out.println("Connection could not be established!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: There may be a bug in createTable() method as it drops the database and recreate it.Check your code in createTable() method definition.

Comment: @YashChudasama Hi Yash, you are right. Not in the createTable() but in another file the table was being dropped while performing initializing operations. You may add this as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks.